# AJAX request fetching additional records from the service

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have defined data parameters of AJAX request as follows

```
"{"take":200,"reportId":"D:\\Sample\\Listbox sample\\DashboardServiceInstaller\\DashboardServiceInstaller\\DashboardServiceInstaller\\listbox sample.sydx","controlId":"ListBox_1","masterData":"[{\"Key\":\"ListBox_1\",\"Value\":[{\"Items\":[]}],\"MultiSelection\":false,\"Filter\":\"Exclude\"}]","rangeData":"[]","modifiedConnectionStrings":"\"\"","listboxRowCount":"1096","currentUser":"null","isPublic":false,"skip":800}"
```

and ajax request is defined as follows

```
$.ajax({
     beforeSend : ()
     cache : true
     contentType : "application/json; charset=utf-8"
     crossDomain : undefined
     data: "{"take":200,"reportId":"D:\\Sample\\Listbox sample\\DashboardServiceInstaller\\DashboardServiceInstaller\\DashboardServiceInstaller\\listbox sample.sydx","controlId":"ListBox_1","masterData":"[{\"Key\":\"ListBox_1\",\"Value\":[{\"Items\":[]}],\"MultiSelection\":false,\"Filter\":\"Exclude\"}]","rangeData":"[]","modifiedConnectionStrings":"\"\"","listboxRowCount":"1096","currentUser":"null","isPublic":false,"skip":800}"
    dataType : "json"
    ejPvtData : Object
    error : ()
    jsonp : "callback"
    processData : false
    success : ()
    type : "POST"
    url : "http://localhost:3002/DashboardService.svc/GetListBoxRows"
```

})

Once ajax request raise to the service, the request url and Request Payload as follows

> Request URL:http://localhost:3002/DashboardService.svc/GetListBoxRows

and Request Payload

> 1. controlID : "ListBox_1"
> 2. currentUser:"null"
> 3. isPublic:false
> 4. listboxRowCount:"1096"
> 5. masterData:"[{"Key":"ListBox_1","Value":[{"Items":[]}],"MultiSelection":false,"Filter":"Exclude"}]"
> 6. modifiedConnectionStrings:""""
> 7. rangeData:"[]"
> 8. reportId:"D:\Sample\Listbox sample\DashboardServiceInstaller\DashboardServiceInstaller\DashboardServiceInstaller\listbox
>      sample.sydx"
> 9. skip:600
> 10. take:200

My requirement : I need to fetch the 200 records only from the service but it has fetching 201 records, even though i defined take 200.

> data.d Array[201] [0 … 99] [100 … 199] 200 : Object

Length is 201

Why i am getting additional data, is there any way to fix this issue.

Comment: How you are managing the length of data in the backend

Comment: Can you post a part of backend code?